# How can disable deploy in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, open-policy-agent

We provide kubernetes cluster for many users, the separation between applications by namespace.

For deploy use kubernetes-helm. There are situations when we need to close the opportunity to deploy the app in the cluster. One option is to change permissions for default sa (which the use kubernetes-helm).

How else can solve?

Comment: We are also having similar situation. Many users, many applications and separated by `namespace`. We are having `tiller` in each namespace and which can deploy only in that namespace. In this way we can more granular control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use an [admission controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/).

Unfortunately, this might involve writing some code to manage it. There are tools out there that help, like [Open Policy Agent](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/kubernetes-admission-control.html)